# ng-submit action called after ng-click

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying a demo mentioned in AngularJS book by O'Reilly.
I know that when there is one input field in the form, hitting enter key inside that input, would cause both `ng-click` and `ng-submit` action to be triggered. However, in my case, I have only one input field, even if I do not press enter key inside the input field, my ng-submit action is called everytime when i click on reset button.
Here is code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Submit Action</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form ng-submit="requestFunding()"
          ng-controller="FormController">
        Estimate :
        <input ng-model="estimate"/>
        <br/>
        Recommended :
        {{recommended}}
        <br/>
        <Button>Fund My Start Up</Button>
        <Button ng-click="reset()">Reset</Button>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        function FormController($scope)
        {
            $scope.estimate = 0;

            computeNeeded = function(){
                $scope.recommended = $scope.estimate * 10;
            };

            $scope.$watch('estimate', computeNeeded);

            $scope.requestFunding = function()
            {
                window.alert("Add More Customers First");
            };

            $scope.reset = function()
            {
                $scope.estimate = 0;
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any logical or conceptual mistake ?
Please also enlighten my on the right way to submit and reset the form when I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In stardard html, you need to set `type="reset"` to indicate that this is a reset button:

```
 <button type="reset" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
```

But you would see a problem with this approach in angular, as this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rf1h2M04e0b4cEPPGLCj?p=preview) shows. When you click `Reset`, the input is set to **empty instead of 0** as you specify in your code:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.estimate = 0;
};
```

The reason for this problem is that your `$scope.reset` runs first and is **overwritten** by the **default action** of the browser for the reset button (clear the form inputs).

In angular, you need to do differently, you need to `preventDefault` and use `form.$setPristine()` to reset the form input states:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="requestFunding()" ng-controller="FormController"> //give the form a name
    Estimate :
    <input ng-model="estimate" />
    <br/>Recommended : {{recommended}}
    <br/>
    <button>Fund My Start Up</button>
    <button ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); reset(); form.$setPristine();">Reset</button>
  </form>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/49pzDy4Q5sGEjylCXipR?p=preview)

Quouted from the docs for $[setPristine](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController):

> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the
>   form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also
>   propagate to all the controls contained in this form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want
>   to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using ng-submit, use ng-click to call requestFunding(), it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give your buttons proper types to control if they are submitting the form - e.g:

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">
```