# How to read data inserted in ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic framework.I am trying to create a login page.I want to read data inserted in username and pass word fields in login.html.I tried to read using $scope but that didn't work.I tried to use console.log() to print the variables in console but i am getting an error saying it is "undefined".I am new to ionic and angularjs.

login.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="menuContent">
<ion-header-bar>
<h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
<form >
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" ng-click="loginNew()">Log in</button>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <span class="input-label">New user?</span>
     <button class="button button-block button-positive"   ng-click="signNew()">Signup</button>
    </label>

  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js:

```
.state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

controller.js:

```
//start LoginCtrl
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$http' , function($scope,$state,$http) {
$scope.signNew=function(){
console.log("sas");
$state.go('app.signup');
console.log("sas");
};
$scope.loginNew = function($scope){
        console.log($scope.user+"   daww");
        console.log($scope.pass);
        $http.get("http://demo.pillocate.com/webservice/Login?Username="+$scope.user+"&Password="+$scope.pass)
            .success(function(data) {    
            alert("Login was Successful.");
            console.log("Login success" + data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
            alert("Wrong Credentials!!Username or Password was Wrong.")
            });

}
}])
//end LoginCtrl
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//start SignupCtrl
.controller('SignupCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope) {


}]);
//end SignupCtrl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use **form** in your HTML then go for **ng-submit** not
>   **ng-click**, because ng-click not validate your html. **Example:** If you use required in input box then ng-click not validate required so use
>   **ng-submit**

See this Documentation [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

> **Note**: It is not compulsory to use **ng-submit** it is just and best
>   practices which we have to follow

And as per you problem you have to pass one object from html and get this object in controller. it will solve your problem.

```
<form ng-submit="loginNew(login)">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="login.user" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="login.pass" placeholder="Password">
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" >Log in</button>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
    <span class="input-label">New user?</span>
     <button class="button button-block button-positive">Signup</button>
    </label>

  </div>
</form>
```

Now in controller :

```
$scope.loginNew = function(mylodinObject){
        console.log(mylodinObject.user+"   daww");
        console.log(mylodinObject.pass);
        $http.get("http://demo.pillocate.com/webservice/Login?Username="+mylodinObject.user+"&Password="+mylodinObject.pass)
            .success(function(data) {    
            alert("Login was Successful.");
            console.log("Login success" + data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
            alert("Wrong Credentials!!Username or Password was Wrong.")
            });

}
```

Some time if you want to use both ng-click and ng-submit then you will be in problem so for that refere this link it will solve your problem :[ng-click and ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321583/ng-submit-action-called-after-ng-click)

Comment: You have to use login.user in ng-modal and it was my mistake i wrote wrong function name in ng-submit now you can see in code i removed ng-click and in ng-submit is use loginNew function now it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81070/discussion-between-devunuri-saipraneeth-and-keval-bhatt).

Answer (score 1):

Design the form as follows

```
<form >
     <div class="list">
       <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
           <span class="input-label">Username</span>
           <input type="text" ng-model="xxx.user" placeholder="Email or Phone">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="xxx.pass" placeholder="Password">
       </label>
       <label class="item">
         <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" ng-click="loginNew(xxx)">Log in</button>
      </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in controller

```
 $scope.loginNew = function(xxx){
     console.log(xxx); // this gives the user and pass variables from form 
     console.log(xxx.user); //for user
     console.log(xxx.pass); //for pass
};
```

Comment: When i do console.log(xxx) I get undefined

Comment: have u add xxx in ng-model in form?

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you. So please accept/ tick my answer

Comment: how to access user and pass individually

Comment: Sorry I dont have enough reputation.You should like my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81066/discussion-between-devunuri-saipraneeth-and-s-vinesh).

Answer (score 1):

```
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$log','$scope','$state','$http' , function($log,$scope,$state,$http) {
    $log.debug($scope.user);
 $log.debug($scope.pass);

Need not pass $scope as the parameter here
    $scope.loginNew = function(){
    $log.debug($scope.user);
 $log.debug($scope.pass);
            $http.get("http://demo.pillocate.com/webservice/Login?Username="+$scope.user+"&Password="+$scope.pass)
                .success(function(data) {    
                alert("Login was Successful.");
                $log.debug("Login success" + data);
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                alert("Wrong Credentials!!Username or Password was Wrong.")
                });

    }
    }])
```

Comment: getting it as undefined

Comment: when you click Log in, does it print the username and password on the console?